# Regular expression to find a string immediately preceding a date

Tags: regex, perl

I am not very familiar with a regular expression. Can you help me with a regular expression to select the string that immediately precedes the date in the below text? Here the result should output :

*GOT222*

Below is the text:

*[2017-11-10 14:00:05] USER=XXX , COMM=RTRV-RET-INF:::::USER_INFO="XXX"; , OWNER=XXX , IP=99.99.999.999
   GOT222 2017-11-10 THU 14:00:05*

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
\S+(?=\s+\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2})
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2SNDYF/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `\S+` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character that is not a white-space
- `(?=\s+\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2})` - positive lookahead to make sure that the current match is followed by 1+ occurrences of a whitespace followed by the date of the format `XXXX-XX-XX` where `X` is a digit.

Comment: Didn't OP ask for `(\S+)` i.e. capture of the desired match?

Answer (score 0):

```
my ($string) = $text =~ /\s(\S+)\s+20[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s/;
```

or

```
my ($string) = $text =~ /\s(\S+)\s+20\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s/a;      # 5.14+
```

Notes:

The leading `\s` is optional. It serves as an optimization.

The trailing `\s` is optional. It serves as to make sure sequences like `2000-00-0001` aren't considered dates. However, it will a string ending with a date from matching.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the string via the end of the sentence.

XXXX....XXXXXXX GOT222 2017-11-10 THU 14:00:05

Find

```
(\w+)\s[\w-]+\s\w+\s[\w:]+$
```

Replace

```
$1
```